# SSHFS performance tanks, why?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, file-transfer, sshfs, gigabit-ethernet

I have two Ubuntu 22.10 computers connected one to another via SSHFS. When I copy small files there is no problem but... once I start copying several gigabytes of data at a time, the performance sinks to zero for more than half the time. See screenshot.

[image: system monitor stats]

I do not copy thousands of files, rather a few files at a time but those go into several gigabytes at a time. Gigabit ethernet adapters, switch, and category 5e cables. Notice that the CPU usage actually tanks to zero as well.

I tried using compression=no as well as non-default cihpers (arcfour is not supported by ssh it seems). This does nothing. What else can I do to make the transfer sustain a gigabit speed?

Comment: Take a look at your disk performance and that of the sshfs process to see if it's waiting on the disk.

Comment: How do I do that?